# powerpoint VBA public variables not available between slides

Tags: vba, global-variables, powerpoint

I have the following code in a powerpoint vba module. It works at first until the next slide then nothing even though the variable has been set. On slide 1 the msgbox tells me the total slides, but when I get to slide 2 the msgbox tells me 0. How is the variable TotalSlides resetting between slides when it was set on slide 1? What Am I missing here?

```
Public TotalSlides As Integer

Public Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)

   'Gets total slides at slide 1, saves to public var TotalSlides
   If Wn.View.CurrentShowPosition = 1 Then
      With ActivePresentation
        TotalSlides = .Slides(.Slides.Count).SlideNumber
      End With
   End If


   'Test output of Public variable
   MsgBox TotalSlides, vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: [Variable scopes in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/877/declaring-variables/2957/variables#t=201701161627186603749) on Docs.SO. If I understand correctly (not familiar with the PPT object model), your public variable is declared in a class module (a *slide* object). **If** you *need* a global variable, you need to declare it in global scope, in a *standard module*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I should have said,  this variable is declared in a standard module,  module1 to be exact. This is why i am confused by it not working.

Comment: Maybe also include the code you used to set up the event handling, in case that's relevant here

Comment: Works as expected for me on PowerPoint 2016 (PC) x32. I assume this is the only code in the project and that TotalSlides isn't being manipulated elsewhere in the VBA project or from outside the project? Of course, the variable is actually being reset each time the slide show changes slide due to the code being placed in the pseudo event OnSlideShowPageChange but it should (and is for me) being reset to the total number of slides in the deck which is always the same number in this example.

Comment: @Tim, that is all the code there is to achieve what needs to be done in this example.

Comment: @Jamie, strange that it works for you.  I am also using PP 2016.  Yes,  i was hoping the code would  give me the same response through the presentation as i need to call refer to the total at certain slides.  I set this up as a test to make sure it would work but at a loss as to why it doesn't,  especially since it appears to work for you.  I'll try a few restarts etc and see if that helps and will post the outcome. I have a feeling that pp if experiencing any errors leaves some sort of residual bug which messes with code. I had been doing some other vba code recently which caused pp to restar

Comment: Works for me too (sorry not a big PPT VBA user, so wasn't aware the event handlers can go in a regular module...)

Comment: Ok, strange stuff. Restarted computer, sort of fixed the problem. The variable now exists through each slide change. But my code above technically shouldn't work as written as running code on a slidechange event on slide 1 won't actually execute because there is no slide change. It appears to work if you leave the page and go back to it. Either way, restart fixed it, now just need to call the code with a different method. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @Tim There are 4 legacy "psuedo" handlers from a long time ago that do not require the more recent class method of event handling in PowerPoint. I wrote an article about it here : http://youpresent.co.uk/powerpoint-application-events-in-vba/

Comment: @MrK the event you're using "should" fire when you start the slide show (it does on my text machine). So if you have a deck of 3 slides, you will get one message as the show starts on slide 1 (or other slide depending on setup) and another 2 as you proceed to slide 2 and 3.